# Proper positioning of UIToolBar at the bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uikit

Due to lack of practice with creating UIToolBar element, I don't fully understand what is the cleanest way to position UIToolBar at the bottom of the screen. Now my code looks like this:

```
private lazy var toolBar: UIToolbar = {  
    let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
    toolBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let addNewNote = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .compose, target: toolBar, action: nil)
    let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: toolBar, action: nil)
    toolBar.items = [spacer, addNewNote]
    
    return toolBar
}()

private func setUpConstraints() {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        toolBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        toolBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        toolBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
    ])
}
```

This gives desired results, however I feel like I am missing a better way to implement this simple element. First of all, once the device is rotated, ToolBar doesn't fill all the space from leading to trailing, secondly assigning both leading/trailing constraints and width/height based on UIScreen.bounds property just doesn't seem right, although previously I saw a constraints layout issue of ToolBarElement in the console before I assigned this strange frame to my ToolBar. Now this issue is gone, but the situation did not become clearer.

My goal is to clone UIToolBar from iOS native notes app [image: see the bottom of screenshot]

So, as an experiences iOS developer (of course you are!) what would you recommend me to do?

Have a nice day!

Comment: No need to add the tool bar manually. You can use the view controller’s toolbar. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621874-settoolbaritems

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well you can do it with autolayaout:

Declare your objects under your controller class:

```
let toolBar: UIToolbar = {
//let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)) // remove this
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let addNewNote = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .compose, target: toolBar, action: nil)
    let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: toolBar, action: nil)
     toolBar.tintColor = .yourColor
    let toolBarTitleLabel = UILabel()
    toolBarTitleLabel.text = "150 Results"
    toolBarTitleLabel.sizeToFit()
    toolBarTitleLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
    toolBarTitleLabel.textColor = .white
    toolBarTitleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    let topBarButtonItemTitleLabel = UIBarButtonItem(customView: toolBarTitleLabel)
    toolBar.items = [spacer, topBarButtonItemTitleLabel, spacer, addNewNote]
    
    return toolBar
}()

let mylabel2: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Your results data text here..."
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = .gray
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return label
}()

let dummyView: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return v
}()
```

In viewDidLoad set constraints:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .black
    
    view.addSubview(toolBar)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        toolBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        toolBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        toolBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
    ])
    
    view.addSubview(mylabel2)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        mylabel2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: toolBar.topAnchor),
        mylabel2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 30),
        mylabel2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -30),
        mylabel2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
    ])
    
    view.addSubview(dummyView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        dummyView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mylabel2.topAnchor),
        dummyView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mylabel2.leadingAnchor),
        dummyView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mylabel2.trailingAnchor),
        dummyView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 30)
    ])
}
```

This is the result:

[image]